# How to convert Char to String in Julia?

Tags: string, char, julia

In julia, Char and String are not comparable.

```
julia> 'a' == "a"
false
```

How can I convert a Char value to a String value?

I have tried the following functions, but none of them work.

```
julia> convert(String, 'a')
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Char to an object of type String

julia> String('a')
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Char to an object of type String

julia> parse(String, 'a')
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching parse(::Type{String}, ::Char)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The way is

```
string(c)
```

e.g.

```
julia> string('')
""
```

The `string` function works to turn anything into its string representation, in the same way it would be `print`ed. Indeed

```
help?> string
search: string String stringmime Cstring Cwstring RevString readstring

  string(xs...)

  Create a string from any values using the print function.

  julia> string("a", 1, true)
  "a1true"
```

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to add that the uppercase `String` constructor can be successfully used on `Vector{Char}`, just not on a single char, for which you'd use the lowercase `string` function. The difference between these two really got me confused.

In summary:

- To create a char vector from a string: `a = Vector{Char}("abcd")`
- To create a string from a char vector: `s = String(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`
- To create a string from a single char: `cs = string('a')`